# Why elements can be inserted in a vector when using const_iterators

Tags: c++, c++14, const-iterator

Considering the code below,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> value{22, 23, 25, 34, 99};
    auto it = find(value.cbegin(), value.cend(), 25);
    value.insert(it, 77);
    return 0;
}
```

Here `it` is a `const_iterator`. Before the insertion, it points to `25`. After the insertion, it points to `77`. Wouldn't this be considered a modification?

Comment: you aren't modifying the vector via the iterator, `value` (which is not const) is modifying itself

Comment: Note that `vector::insert` and `vector::erase` (or, for that matter, corresponding methods of other standard containers) only accept `const_iterator` since C++11. I.e. there was probably a proposal that made it into C++11, and which gives a rationale for the change.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A `const_iterator` prevents you from modifying the element that iterator points to, it does not prevent you from modifying the container itself.

In your example you're finding an iterator to the element `25`, and inserting `77` before `25`. You're not modifying the value `25`.

> Before the insertion, `it` points to `25`. After the insertion, it points to `77`.

[`vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) always invalidates the iterators at and after the point of insertion. So if you dereference `it` in your example after `insert`, it's undefined behavior. Instead you could do

```
it = value.insert(it, 77);
// it points to 77, the newly inserted element
// (it + 1) points to 25
```

Answer (score 1):

`cosnt_iterator` points to const value. It means when you dereference it then it will return `const` object. The iterator can be modified but not the object that iterator points to.

```
vector<int> value{22, 23, 25, 34, 99};
std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = find(value.cbegin(), value.cend(), 25);
it = value.insert(it, 77); // valid 
*it = 77;                  // Error
```

Think is like pointer to `const` objects. When you declare

```
int const a = 10;
int const *ptr = &a;
```

then `ptr` can be modified but the object `ptr` is pointing to shall not.

```
*ptr = 5         // Error
int const b = 0;
ptr = &b;        // Valid
```